# Domain AND Page Specific Javascript Load error on App Engine

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I have a very weird page specific error on App Engine with Javascript.
The Page loads in other domains and works perfectly.
Other similar pages in the problem domain also work perfectly.
If you go to any of these
    http://headlessuber.com/place.php
    http://solomonschariot.com/place.php 
    http://clintoncars.us/place.php

and type in Space Needle for the location and tab the Lattitude appears, but if you go 
    http://fastlanesplease.com/place.php
and do the same it does not.
It also works on other pages with identical structures in this and other domains ????

Comment: When I duplicate the file and the javascript file the same behavior occurs see   http://headlessuber.com/placee.php that works and http://fastlanesplease.com/placee.php which also does not ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MissingKeyMapError    Error** 
The script element that loads the API is missing the required authentication parameter. If you are using the standard Maps JavaScript API, you must use a key parameter with a valid API key. If you are a Premium Plan customer, you must use either a client parameter with your client ID or a key parameter with a valid API key.

See the guide to API keys and client IDs.

Comment: This is confusing. I must be using an old version because <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script> has worked just fine for what I need and continues to on all the other domains (same line for any domain). I have an api key and oauth for logins all work fine. Is this a new change ??

Comment: Thank you You were right, that worked. Was I getting the benefit of legacy code or something for it to work on all the older domains? Anyway thanks, will put your star up shortly